# Reading an MP4 with OpenCV and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I am working in a C++/OpenGL interactive app, and I decided to use OpenCV to read videos so that I can get them from the host into the GPU as a texture. I've succeeded so far when using an input that is persistent like a web camera, but I am having trouble with MP4 files as they have a non-perpetual duration. I don't know how to handle that. I am getting the frames in my main's render loop, so if I decide to stop the iterations when the video finishes streaming, my app will close and I don't want that, I guess there must be a workaround, like looping the video (I tried by checking if the *frame.empty()* and either overloading the VideoCapture or reseting the video frame but only got *(!_src.empty()) in cv::cvtColor*), the other solution I though about was doing another loop before my render loop to do the decoding but it's not the most performance-wise desicion I am using this code:

```
// Import openCV.
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

// Open the MP4 and its attributes.
std::string videoName = "D:\\\SomeVideo\\\Video.mp4";

    VideoCapture cap( videoName  );
    if( !cap.isOpened() )
    {

        std::cout << "Video file not loaded!" << std::endl;
        return -1;

    }

Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
int videoWidth = frame.rows;
int videoHeight = frame.cols;
unsigned char* image = cvMat2TexInput( frame );

// We create the texture that will store our video.
unsigned int video;
glGenTextures( 1, &video );
glBindtexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, video );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

// Render Loop.
while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
{

    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &WIDTH, &HEIGHT );

    // We set our video.
    try
    {

        cap >> frame;

        if( frame.empty() )
        {

            break;

        }

        else
        {

            image = cvMat2TexInput( frame );

        }

    }

    catch( Exception& e )
    {

        std::cout << e.msg << std::endl;

    }

    if( image )
    {

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, videoWidth, videoHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

    }

    else
    {

        std::cout << "Failed to load video texture." << std::endl;

    }

    // Input.
    processInput( window );

    // Go on until I bind it to my program, here:
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, video );

    // Finish all the boilerplate...
```

And here is my utility function to link the cvMat to an unsigned char* for OpenGL:

```
// Utility function to link OpenCV.
unsigned char* cvMat2TexInput( Mat& img )
{

    cvtColor( img, img, COLOR_BGR2RGB );
    transpose( img, img );
    flip( img, img, 1 );
    flip( img, img, 0 );
    return img.data;

}
```

Comment: You could check if `cap >> frame` succeeds. Off-topic: You don't need triple-backslashes in your filepath.

Comment: I tried that one also, but I think that the problem lies in resetting the *cap >> frame*, more than testing when to (I tried testing equality of *cap.get( CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT )* to a *frameCounter* variable also as this post suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057234/opencv-how-to-restart-a-video-when-it-finishes), I will try it again anyway. Thanks

Comment: So, you want to have that video repeat indefinitely?

Comment: It could be that or just stopping when the video has ended, maybe playing it in reverse I am just looking for a creative answer that solves the breaking of the render loop, maybe even silencing the *cv::Exception at memory location error occurs* I don't know, this is my "Hello World!" OpenCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the frame index to be read next with:

```cpp
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
```

(From the documentation linked below): `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`: 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next

Doing this once

```cpp
frame.empty()
```

returns `true` should suffice.

Documentation for [cv::VideoCapture.set()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) and [cv::VideoCaptureProperties
Flags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d)